Is "sid" property mandatory for custom "profileUrl" for "UserProvider" from auth0?
I'm trying to override the default /api/auth/me endpoint from nextjs-auth0 module in my NextJS app and use my own endpoint to return the profile data of the user once they are logged in using Auth0.
As of now, the original /api/auth/me endpoint returns a structure similar to below.
{
    "customer_uuid": "15e923fa-edb9-4c60-a44b-360838f9d1f4",
    "nickname": "Red Dragon",
    "name": "Brave Strong",
    "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/15e923fa-edb9-4c60-a44b-360838f9d1f4?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Feh.png",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-13T19:41:59.977Z",
    "email": "brave.strong@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "sub": "auth0|14df61794b7455102561p5za",
    "sid": "30fVsNbj4mFAVnt77gBREEZeDBb6ZW03"
}

I don't use sid inside my app. But I am wondering whether it is being used by either nextjs-auth0 or auth0 modules and my custom API would need to return a proper value for sid (I assume sid represents the session ID).
Do I need to return an sid? If so, what is the format of an sid?
